# AspNet Core with IIS Express requires Windows Auth credentials every time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, windows-authentication, iis-express

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 7 app with the Windows authentication/authorization based on AD groups. While it works fine in production, during the debugging it is a bit annoying as every time I launch the server hosted in IIS Express and I reach any endpoint that requires authentication, the default Windows prompt appears and I need to provide the domain credentials.

If I stopp the server (IIS Express) and launch it again, it asks for the credentials again. And again with every relaunch of the IIS Express.

I think some time ago it worked differently, that I was asked for the credentials only after some time period (like after couple of hours of inactivity), but I do not have any evidence for that.

Is there any way how to preserve the authentication scheme (not need to fall back to anonymous auth) and just preserve the given credentials in IIS Express for multiple re-launches? Or store it somehow locally in the webconfig?

Comment: Windows authentication doesn't work the way you imagined, so the only way to get rid of the prompt is to configure your browser properly to perform pre-authentication. Different browsers require different configuration and your domain administrators are the best resources to assist.